# How set variable ejs in property name on input

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have problem because I would use my variable ejs in property name which is  in input . I don't have idea how that do it .

```
<main>

    <h1> Witaj
        <%= login %>
    </h1>
    <ul>
        <% for(let sub of subject) { %>
        <li>
            <%=sub.sub %>
            <form method="POST" action="/change">
                <input name="<%- sub.sub %>><input type="submit">
            </form>

            <%=sub.rating %>
        </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
```

I need receive in script.js variable `"<%- sub.sub %>"` .
Please about help me .

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in input declaration, try this instead

```
<form method="POST" action="/change">
   <input name="<%- sub.sub %>" type="submit">
</form>
```